# What is this data type, and how to convert it into Integer?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

[image]

I have attached a digital Weighing Indicator to my computer via RS-232 and it is giving me the following data on Hyper Terminal (please see the image attached).
What is this data type and how can I convert it into Integer in VB.NET?

Comment: Please add information such as vendor and model of Digital Weighing Indicator, programming manual or notification data format. Also, for the received data, it will be easier to understand the data pattern if you convert binary data to hexadecimal character string instead of a screenshot of the character string as it is.

Comment: "How to convert smiley faces and hearts into integers?"

Comment: What is the encoding option on your terminal?

Comment: Is there a VB question here?

Comment: You need to consult the documentation for the hardware to learn what data to expect from it. You don't just use trial and error.